# How to make the newly created process be a parent to itself

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am playing with Win32 functions that are responsible for working with processes, and when I call `CreateProcessA()`, a process is created, but its parent is either PowerShell - when the program is called from PowerShell console - or via cmd.exe, then the process's parent is "explorer.exe".

Can someone give me a hint, or give me some starting point?

What I would like to achieve is that the process I am running does not have a parent, but is a parent itself.

Comment: The parent of the new process should be the process that is actually calling CreateProcess(). What are you looking at that is saying otherwise?

Comment: Try to reason with this in the real world. You want a child to become its own parent. If it's been given birth...there's no going back. Put that child for adoption or whatever, that child can never become its own parent.

Comment: ok that makes sense, now i understand the error in my thinking. I wondered if it was just possible.

Comment: The child-parent relationship is recorded by the OS, but not used for anything useful. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Strictly speaking, the parent process (the process which created the child process) is not actually recorded. recorded process from which child is inherited (*InheritedFromUniqueProcessId*). usual this is parent. but not always

Comment: I don't know exactly yet ;) . But what prompted me to this idea is that some system services look like they don't have a parent, you can see it in "process explorer" for example. In a tree like "Firefox" or "explorer.exe" they look like they don't have parents, so I wanted to do the same, create a parent.

Comment: When I enter the "Firefox" process properties, from the "explorer process" level, in the "Image" tab there is a field called "Parent", and for me this field has the value: <Non-existent Process> (someID)

Comment: *"explorer.exe" they look like they don't have parents* - simply that parent( inheritedfrom) process already exit.